# Deriving the label names from other node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using ne04j 2.1.2 community edition.

I have a nodes with a label called `Company` and I created these nodes and label by loading CSV  file along with the MERGE and CREATE commands. 
So in future if my label names changes,say `Company` to `Organization`, I wanted to maintain the createddate, UpdatedDate, NewLabelName, OldLabelName values somewhere.

So in order to achieve that I thought of maintaining one master node which holds the label information i.e., it should have the properties like NewLabelName, OldLabelName, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate. So the label name should come from the Master Node to other nodes. Whenever we made any changes to label ,then the corresponding `UpdatedDate` property value should be updated in the master node and NewLabelName should come from the master node to other nodes (nodes for which that label belongs to) .

Hope you understand the scenario here.

But how can i achieve this ? is it possible to achieve ? if yes, then how can i define the relationship between master and other nodes?
(Here my other nodes are Name of the Companies like Google, Yahoo, Samsung etc.. and those will be having some other child nodes like location)

Please suggest the solution. (I wanted to achieve these using cypher not using java)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although labels can be changed, you should do that rarely (e.g., to recover from a mistake). Changing a large number of labels is *very* expensive and should never be done as a part of normal processing.

Also, like a Java class name, a label name is not something you'd normally show to end users. So, there is really no reason to ever change them. Just try to pick reasonable label names to start with, and don't plan to change them.

Comment: Yes, I understand not to change the label name very frequently or in the beginning itself i need to choose the reasonable name. But my requirement is in future the label name might change . So  i wanted to make that change happen only to the master node where label is defined and wanted to maintain other properties as well in the master node. If i change the label there it should reflect in the below subsequent nodes. How can i do this?

Comment: You can have the label and common property values only in a single "master" node that has relationships (e.g., with the type `CHILD`) to every other node (that "shares" that label and the common property values). This way, changing a label or a shared property value only has to be done in the master node.

The only drawback is that queries will be longer -- something like `MATCH (m:myLabel)-[:CHILD]->(n {name:"Fred"})` instead of `MATCH (n:myLabel {name:"Fred"})`. But, since there would only be 1 node labelled `myLabel`, the effect should be negligible.